How to export a list of Datasets in separate sheets in XLSX?
I can export a Dataset correctly using:
$dataset=Dataset[...];
Export["...path...file.xlsx",$dataset,{"XLSX"}]

Also, I can export Values in a Dataset on separate sheets using:
$datasets={"Sheet1"->Values@Normal@Dataset[...],"Sheet2"->Values@Normal@Dataset[...],...};
Export["...path...file.xlsx",$dataset,{"XLSX","Rules"}]

How do I export a list of Datasets not the values in their association in separate sheets in XLSX? I tried the following:
$datasets={"Sheet1"->Dataset[...],"Sheet2"->Dataset[...],...};
Export["...path...file.xlsx",$dataset,{"XLSX","Rules"}]

It doesn't work. I don't understand how these specifications work. Help please!

Either it is not supported yet or there is some weird syntax for it. Anyway, you can make it work by evaluating the following code:
System`Convert`ExcelDump`ToSheets[{data_Dataset}] := (
    Dataset;
    System`Convert`ExcelDump`ToSheets @ Dataset`DatasetSVList @ data
);

Then, the following code should work (at least it does in v14.1):
d1 = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];
d2 = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}];
Export["test.xlsx", "Sheets" -> {"Titanic" -> d1, "Planets" -> d2}, "Rules"]


This is fixed in 14.2. Thanks for the proposed workaround @Domen. I would suggest this slight change for 14.1 and prior, but if that ends up working too, great :)
System`Convert`ExcelDump`ToSheets[data:{__Dataset}] := (
    Dataset;
    ToSheets[Dataset`DatasetSVList/@ data]
)

